# Solution of a differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

how can one solve the equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\phi}{du}+\frac{1}{u}\phi = (\gamma-x_{0}\beta u)\phi^{2}
\end{equation}
where $\gamma, x_{0}, \beta$ are constants?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange! Can you be a bit more specific: Is there an initial condition? Do you want a solution to exist for $t = 0$? Where does the problem come from? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Set $\psi=1/\phi$, then 
$$-\frac{d\psi}{du}+\frac{\psi}{u}=(γ−x_0βu),$$
which is a linear DE in $\psi$.